# Pinescript line extend

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Trying to draw Bull/bear flags and make the lines extend as long as the price is still within the top and bottom lines.
The problem is if the future prices comes back into where the flag lines would be, it extends them to that current point as seen in the image below.
I have tried adding many conditions in to stop this from happening e.g. the code below:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Line Extension", overlay=true, max_lines_count=20)

ph = ta.pivothigh(high,5,5)
pl = ta.pivotlow(low,5,5)

plotshape(ph, color=#FF0000, location=location.abovebar, offset=-5)
plotshape(pl, color=#00E600, location=location.belowbar, offset=-5)

var line [] flag_array = array.new_line()

var flag_price      = array.new_float()
var flag_index      = array.new_int()
var flag_price2      = array.new_float()
var flag_index2      = array.new_int()

var lastIn = 0


arraySize = input.int(20, title="Array Size")

add_to_array(_price,_index,_val) =>
    array.unshift(_price,_val)
    array.unshift(_index,bar_index)
    if array.size(_index)>arraySize
        array.pop(_price)
        array.pop(_index)

if ph 
    add_to_array(flag_price,flag_index,ph)

if pl 
    add_to_array(flag_price2,flag_index2,pl)


draw_lines(_price, _index, _lineArray)=>
    if array.size(_index)>=4
        x1      = array.get(_index,1)-5
        y1      = array.get(_price,1)
        x2      = array.get(_index,0)-5
        y2      = array.get(_price,0)
        array.push(_lineArray, line.new(x1,y1,x2,y2, color=color.white))

    array.clear(_price) 
    array.clear(_index)


extend_lines(lineArray,_close,_index)=>
    if array.size(lineArray)>1
        recentLine  = array.get(lineArray,0)
        olderLine   =  array.get(lineArray,1)
        x1       = line.get_x1(recentLine) 
        y1       = line.get_y1(recentLine)
        x2       = line.get_x2(recentLine)
        y2       = line.get_y2(recentLine)
        
        x11       = line.get_x1(olderLine)
        y11       = line.get_y1(olderLine)
        x22       = line.get_x2(olderLine)
        y22       = line.get_y2(olderLine)
        
        slope       = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
        slope2      = (y22-y11)/(x22-x11)
        
        currentDistance = _index - x2
        currentDistance2 = _index - x22

        currentY2 = y2 + (currentDistance*slope)
        currentY22 = y22 + (currentDistance2*slope2)

        var closed = false
        if _close<=currentY2 and _close>=currentY22 and closed==false
            //Price within the Flags slope, extend to current price/bar
            line.set_x2(recentLine,_index)
            line.set_y2(recentLine,currentY2)
            line.set_x2(olderLine,_index)
            line.set_y2(olderLine,currentY22)
            //If price exits flag area cancel extension posibility 
        if _close>currentY2 or _close<currentY22
            closed := true


//plot(close)
if array.size(flag_index)>4
    draw_lines(flag_price, flag_index, flag_array)
if array.size(flag_index2)>4
    draw_lines(flag_price2, flag_index2, flag_array)

if array.size(flag_array)>2
    extend_lines(flag_array, close, bar_index)
```

But adding in the last 2 lines of code just stops the flag lines from extending at all.
Any ideas?[flag lines being extended img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odvec.jpg)

Comment: The condition to stop the extension looks correct. Only issue that could be is, if it were to run on the initial bars where line is generated then the close[1] would be beyond the lines. If you can share the line generation part then can check the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cancel plot if bar crosses it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70450206/cancel-plot-if-bar-crosses-it)

Answer (score 0):

Ending the line on crossed and/or candle close above/below + removing it from the array prior performing your final touches should do the trick.

See the following answer from Bjorgum for an example.

[Cancel plot if bar crosses it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70450206/cancel-plot-if-bar-crosses-it/70499138#70499138)